# error initializing an object

Tags: ios, core-data

Below is the beginning of a method that does the same thing all the way down. However I get an error: Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class 'Car'

What am I doing wrong, thank you.

```
- (Car*) initWithJSONData:(NSDictionary *)responseData {
    BOOL isActive;
    self = [super init];

    Car*coreDataCar =(Car*)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Car" inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
    //Check if car is active or deactive.
    if (![responseData valueForKeyIsNull:@"Car Status"]) {
        int carStatus = [[responseData valueForKey:@"Car Status"] intValue];
        if (carStatus == 1 ) {//active
            isActive=YES;
        }else if( carStatus == 2 ){
            isActive = NO;
        }
    }


    if (![responseData valueForKeyIsNull:@"Name"]) {
        [coreDataCar setValue:[responseData valueForKey:@"Name"] forKey:@"name"];
    }
    NSLog(@"user count = %@",[responseData valueForKey:@"UserCount"]);//Sometimes it crashes here, others it doesnt
    if (![responseData valueForKeyIsNull:@"UserCount"]) {
        //[responseData valueForKey:@"UserCount"];
        [coreDataCar setValue:[responseData valueForKey:@"UserCount"] forKey:@"userCount"];
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the call it's complaining about:

```
 self = [super init];
```

Later you do this:

```
Car*coreDataCar =(Car*)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Car" inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
```

You should get rid of both of those calls and replace them with something like this:

```
- (id) initWithJSONData:(NSDictionary *)responseData
 inManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *) moc {

    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Car"
                                              inManagedObjectContext:moc];
    if (self = [super initWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:moc]) {

        ...

    }
    return self;
}
```

Note also that init methods conventionally have a return type of `id`.